# java esc/pos close improper

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

I am dealing with a ESC/POS command printer, and I could print something out with the code below.

```
EscPos escpos = new EscPos(printerOutputStream);
escpos.writeLF("Hello Wold");
escpos.feed(1);
escpos.close();
```

But I will have to replug my usb cable or the printer won't have any action afterwards.

Only using these commands for a couple days, but I think the problem might be close improperly.

However I can't find any solutions.

Is there any solutions or it may be some kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to printerOutputStream.close() to close the printer's output stream.